# POST value becomes empty when inserted in MYSQL string, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, string, post

I am sending some values with AJAX POST to a PHP file:
I  know I am getting them because I can see the values sent in the console:

```
table=MENU&colid=MID&id=2&colname=STATUS&value=1
```

But for some strange reason when I insert them into the query string:

```
"UPDATE ".$_POST['table']." SET ".$_POST['colname']." = ".$_POST['value']." 
WHERE ".$_POST['colid']." = ".$_POST['id'];
```

Value is empty when value = 1!!!

```
UPDATE MENU SET STATUS = '' WHERE MID = '2'
```

I solved the problem by changing the variable name value to val, has anybody experienced something similar? is value a keyword or reserved word?

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: do print_r($_POST) and make sure you aren't misspelling the key

Comment: by the way you shouldn't be concatenating values to MySQL strings like that, if those values are provided by a user, then your application is vulnerable to SQL Injection or XSS if you don't do proper validation.

Comment: XSS heaven right here

Comment: Thanks @AlanChavez i do use validation but just to make the question easier I added the POST values directly to the string, but there is lots of validation behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL

```
UPDATE MENU SET STATUS = '' WHERE MID = '2'
```

doesn't actually reflect what you are doing in PHP. The line:

```
"UPDATE ".$_POST['table']." SET ".$_POST['colname']." = ".$_POST['value']." 
WHERE ".$_POST['colid']." = ".$_POST['id'];
```

otherwise should read:

```
"UPDATE ".$_POST['table']." SET ".$_POST['colname']." = '".$_POST['value']."' 
WHERE ".$_POST['colid']." = '".$_POST['id'] . "'";
```

mind the single quotes in your SQL statement which are missing in your PHP code.

Besides this I highly recommend to not send parts of SQL via AJAX from client to server as you are disclosing the internal structure of your database to everyone listening the traffic or just peeping into the data send by the browser.

Comment: Thanks Axel, the quotes are irrelevant because I always get integers as values. The data is sent encrypted and then there is data validation before adding the values to the MySQL string, this is just to make the question easier.

Comment: If I open a browsers console and watch the come and go from you're posts, the values will be decrypted usually.

Comment: I agree, it is not SSL encryption I am talking about, to be honest it is quite complex and I am trying to solve another issue right now, thanks a lot for the advice, really appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST['$id']` doesn't exist. You've only got `$_POST['id']`

Try var_dump/print_r on $_POST to see all the attributes.

As a side note, it looks like you're using the deprecated mysql extension (and putting post values straight into a database query opening up the possibility of SQL injection), I strongly recommend MySQLi.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo while writing the question, the issue is with value in any case not id. I do use mysqli and there is a whole post/get cleaning system behind it but I don't have space to write it all. Thanks, the thing is when echo $_POST['value'] is empty for value = 1 :(

Comment: Then either you have a typo on `value` or `valeu` or you need to dig in to your "cleaning system" a bit more.

Comment: I guess my "cleaning system" is having issues with the variable name "value" I'll have to double check, I was just wondering if this was some kind of common problem when value = 1. But i guess it is my validation script. Thanks @AxelAmthor